# Mostrar data na MessageBox C#

Tags: c#, datetime, data

tenho um vetor de datas com os valores já inseridos, porém queria mostrar os valores um a um, então criei um "for" que fizesse isso
DatasIndisponíveis é o meu vetor de datas, com os valores já alocados;

```
string mens;
 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  {
   mens += @DatasIndisponiveis[i].ToString();
  }
 MessageBox.Show(@mens,"Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Ele simplesmente não executa a Messagebox logo depois de receber o valor do formato data ( Parece que como a data vem no formato dd/mm/yyyy ele não consegue usar as "/")

Answer (score 1):

porque dos @ no nome das variáveis ?

se você tem um array de datas, ficaria assim:

```
DateTime[] datas = new DateTime[5];
string msg = "";
for(int i =0; i< datas.Lenght; i++)
     msg += datas[i].ToShortDateString()+"\r\n";

MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Comment: O "@" nas variáveis era alguns testes que esqueci de retirar. Pois bem, fiz como você descreveu e mesmo assim continuou meu erro. Meu array está declarado por [List<DateTime> DatasIndisponiveis = new List<DateTime>();]

Comment: As barras não importam na string. Poste seu código completo como está por favor

Answer (score 0):

Estou criando um sistema Hoteleiro, para isso preciso saber se não há uma reserva durante o período de check in e check out, então eu explodo a distancia entre as datas (08 ao 10 vira 08-09-10) caso haja alguma reserva neste período eu adiciono valor a uma variável chamada reserva e também esse mesmo dia no array datas indisponíveis, lá na frente eu realizo o teste, o problema é que eu quero mostrar todas os valores dentro do array em uma linha só(ex: "Há reserva nos dias 21,22,23,24,25,26)
Segue o código:

// FUNÇÃO PARA COMPARAR AS DATAS DO CHECK IN E DO CHECKOUT

```
    public List<DateTime> retornadata(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(dt);
        }

        return dates;
    }
```

Agora o código de inserção das datas

try              {

```
                    DateTime start = dtpCheInR.Value;
                    DateTime end = dtpCheOutR.Value;
                    List<DateTime> DatasIndisponiveis = new List<DateTime>();
                    List<DateTime> datas = retornadata(start, end);
                    int reservas = 0;
                    foreach (var data in datas)
                    {
                        string stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM reserva JOIN quarto on (quarto.IdQ = reserva.IdQ) WHERE quarto.NumeroQ= " + txtQuartoR.Text+ " AND CAST('"+ data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"' AS DATE) BETWEEN reserva.CheckinR and reserva.CheckoutR";

                        MySqlCommand comandoSQL = conectabanco.CreateCommand();
                         comandoSQL.CommandText = stringSQL;

                        comandoSQL.Connection = conectabanco; //usar a conexao mComm
                        MySqlDataReader dadosNumQuarto = comandoSQL.ExecuteReader();
                        try
                        {

                            dadosNumQuarto.Read();

                            NumQ = dadosNumQuarto["NumeroQ"].ToString();

                            dadosNumQuarto.Close();

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // Caso ele não tenha encontrado valor ele cai neste catch que possibilita o fechamento do comando de leitura já aberto.
                            dadosNumQuarto.Close();
                            // throw;
                        }
                        if ((NumQ != null)&&(NumQ!=""))
                        {
                            DatasIndisponiveis.Add(data);
                            reservas++;

                        }
                        NumQ = "";
                    }


                    if(reservas > 0)
                    {
// O Erro acontece aqui, ele simplesmente trava

                        for (int i = 0; i < reservas; i++)
                        {
                            msg += @DatasIndisponiveis[i].ToShortDateString() + "\r\n";
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Erro Nova reserva", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                    else
                    {
//Realizo o insert aqui ( já funcionando)
                      }
```